# ajuda com o uso do navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: node.js, react, typescript

estou Produzindo uma amplificador de guitarra para navegador, mais ao capturar o som de qualquer microfone o som esta saindo com flutuações, independente de ser a guitarra ou meu microfone do computador, gravei a saida aqui https://youtu.be/D-XOX2qEL-0

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const MicrophoneApp: React.FC = () => {
const audioRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
const startAudio = async () => {
try {
// Solicitar permissão para o microfone
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

```
    // Criar um contexto de áudio
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();

    // Criar um nó para o microfone
    const microphoneNode = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    // Conectar o nó do microfone ao destino de saída (alto-falantes)
    microphoneNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    // Iniciar a reprodução
    audioContext.resume();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro ao acessar o microfone:', error);
  }
};

startAudio();
```

}, []);

return (



);
};

export default MicrophoneApp;